# why does numpy give the dimension mismatch error?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix I hold in a variable called M.
I then use:

```
 dist = np.dot(M[0], M[0])
```

and I always get the error eventually leading to:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 246, in __mul__
      raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
  ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

I really don't understand how this statement could fail with dimension mismatch - I use the argument M[0] for both first and second array, they are of identical size.

Comment: Show us what `M[0]` contains.

Comment: Do you really mean M is a matrix, or is it just a plain ndarray? If it's an ndarray, what are its dimensions?

Answer (score 3):

If `M` is an X by Y matrix, then `M[0]` is 1 by Y. You can't multiply 2 1-by-Y matrices unless Y is 1.

Comment: `M = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]); np.dot(M[0], M[0])` gives 14, as I expect.

Comment: That's not a [matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). That's an [ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Comment: Good call! Perhaps the OP was expecting the behavior of the ndarray.

Comment: If the OP has `matrix` objects, then `np.dot(M[0], M[0].T)` should give @Prashant's result.